# How to Line Chart this data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create line chart for following data. I would also like to have the ability to hover over each data point to look at the x and y value at that data point. I have the following data structure:

```
x[0] = [23 4 2 2 4 4 5 3 334 2]

y[0] = [6 24 1 2 2 5 1 3 8 0]

x[1] = [5 6 8 6 3 4 6 3 3]

y[1] = [9 7 8 6 3 4 1 9 2]

x[2] = [6 9 9 6 2 5 8 3]

y[2] = [1 0 2 5 6 2 1 5]
```

... so that I will have 3 lines on the same chart.

I played with "Seer" without much success. Can anyone provide any recommendations / examples / references for plotting similar data using Seer or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Give the [lazy_high_charts gem](https://github.com/xiaods/lazy_high_charts) a try.

```
#app/views/layouts/appliction.*
= javascript_include_tag 'highcharts.js'

#Gemfile
gem 'lazy_high_charts'

# my_controller#my_action
x_0 = [23, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 334, 2]
y_0= [6, 24, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 0]

x_1 = [5, 6, 8, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 3]
y_1 = [9, 7, 8, 6, 3, 4, 1, 9, 2]

x_2 = [6, 9, 9, 6, 2, 5, 8, 3]
y_2 = [1, 0, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5]


data_0  = x_0.zip(y_0)
data_1 = x_1.zip(y_1)
data_2  = x_2.zip(y_2)

@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.series(:name => "xy0", :data => data_0)
    f.series(:name => "xy1", :data => data_1)
    f.series(:name => "xy3", :data => data_2)
    f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"line" })
    f.yAxis(:title => { :text => "y axis values" } )
    f.xAxis(:title => { :text => "x axis values"} )
    f.title(:text => "XY Graph")
    f.plotOptions({}) # override the default values that lazy_high_charts puts there
    f.legend({}) # override the default values 
end

#app/views/my_controller/my_action
= high_chart("chart", @h)
```

**Caveat:**

HighCharts is only free for [non-commercial use](http://www.highcharts.com/license). That may or may not be a dealbreaker for you.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. HighCharts looks a great tool. My usage is non-commercial. However, I was unable to get it to work within my application. I followed the same code you posted. The view does not render chart. It just shows up empty. Any clues what might be going wrong is greatly appreciated. Also, I would prefer if I can avoid using jquery since some other code segments on my page do not work with jquery.

Comment: Did you download [highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/download) and add it to your `public/javascripts` folder? Also, Highcharts should work with whatever javascript you already have (jQuery, prototype or mootools).

Comment: I'd like to clarify , that since Rails 3 there's a special folder for all the .js files - app/assets/javascripts . If you are about to use a file from it , you have to make a declaration in application.js manifest file by including it .

Answer (score 0):

I've really liked jQuery flot for this kind of thing:

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Check out the example here:

http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.txt

In your controller or view, you can use Ruby's zip to zip together arrays of x and y values if you need to:

```
> a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
> b = [5,6,7]
 => [5, 6, 7] 
> a.zip(b)
 => [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]
```